# What config affects the keyboard when I'm using xmonad?

Tags: keyboard, xmonad

I'm running Ubuntu 11.10 with xmonad. How do I configure repeat speed and delay of the keyboard? Is there a graphical tool or I'll have to edit some config file?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try `man xset`:

```
$ xset r rate 1000 200
```

will set dalay to one second and repeat rate to 200 chars per second.
This is not xmonad-related, but you can put your `xset` command to the xmonad config:

```
startupHook = spawn "xset r rate 200 20"
```